# fairseq toolkit not using GPU to train NMT model

Tags: python, nlp, gpu, nvidia, training-data

I am training an English-Vietnamese NMT model using fairseq.

fairseq tells that it is training the model on 1 GPU. However, when I check the GPU, It seems not to be used and the training process is very slow.

[screenshot: GPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8paQ.jpg)

Training on 63k sentences corpus: an epoch takes about 1 hours. (model: fconv)

Training on 233k sentences corpus: an epoch takes about 4 hours. (model: transformer)

[screenshot: console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atXeg.jpg)

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 and the CUDA version is 10.2.

**Am I successfully training the model on GPU?**

Glad to see your solutions/suggestions.

Comment: Did you try forcing it to use CPU and see if it’s even slower?

Comment: @SamH. It actually is using CPU, not GPU. When I check torch.cuda.is_available(), it returns False.